# Jhipster : Why cache is not working?

Tags: caching, spring-data-jpa, ehcache, jhipster

I am working on cache on Jhipster project. I want to use cache on User Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
// attributes, getters and setters
}
```

I configure ehcache.xml file :

```
  <cache name="com.domain.User"
           timeToIdleSeconds="1800"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600">
    </cache>
```

dev yml file

```
spring:
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false # we use gulp + BrowserSync for livereload
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:xxx/cccccccc
        name: ccc
        username: cc
        password: cc
    jpa:
        database-platform: com.util.PostgreSQL82Dialect
        database: POSTGRESQL
        show_sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: true
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
    jhipster:
        cache: # Hibernate 2nd level cache, used by CacheConfiguration
            timeToLiveSeconds: 180
            ehcache:
                maxBytesLocalHeap: 16M
```

When i log in my application user is fetch from database. I log out and log on, the user is always fetch from database. 
Is there another configuration to add ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cache the query result. You need to use [Cache Abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) in Spring.

In your Entity repository, you need to add something like(the code is from the above link):

```
@Cacheable("books")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```

annotation `@Cacheable` triggers cache population. `@Cache` is adding cache stragegy for the entity.